# How does Python interpret backslash in string?

Tags: python

Although I noticed the pattern but how does the backslash work in string theoretically?

```
'@#2_#]&*^%$\]'
```

**output**: `'@#2_#]&*^%$\\]'`

```
'@#2_#]&*^%$\\]'
```

**output**: `'@#2_#]&*^%$\\]'`

```
'@#2_#]&*^%$\\\]'
```

**output**: `'@#2_#]&*^%$\\\\]'`

Comment: [The "theory".](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your follow-up comment:

> What puzzled me is in my example, it doesn't escape. Single backslash produces double backslashes. Double backslashes produce Double backslashes. Triple backslashes produce quadruple backslashes.....

To be clear: your first output is a string with **one** backslash in it. Python displays two backslashes in its **representation of** the string.

When you input the string with a single backslash, Python does not treat the sequence `\]` in the input as any special escape sequence, and therefore the `\` is turned into an actual backslash in the actual string, and the `]` into a closing square bracket. Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) linked by Klaus D.:

> Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., *the backslash is left in the result*. (This behavior is useful when debugging: if an escape sequence is mistyped, the resulting output is more easily recognized as broken.)

When you input the string with a double backslash, the sequence `\\` is an escape sequence for a **single** backslash, and then the `]` is just a `]`.

Either way, when Python displays the string back to you, it uses `\\` for the single actual backslash, because it does not look ahead to determine that a single backslash would work - the backslash always gets escaped.

---

To go into a little more detail: Python doesn't care about how you specified the string in the first place - it has a specific "normalized" form that depends only on what the string actually contains. We can see this by playing around with the different ways to quote a string:

```
>>> 'foo'
'foo'
>>> "foo"
'foo'
>>> r'foo'
'foo'
>>> """foo"""
'foo'
```

The normalized form will use double quotes if that avoids escape sequences for single quotes:

```
>>> '\'\'\''
"'''"
```

But it will switch back to single quotes if the string contains both types of quote:

```
>>> '\'"'
'\'"'
>>> "'\"'
'\'"'
```

(Exercise: how many characters are actually in this string, and what are they? How many backslashes does the string contain?)

> It contains two characters - a single-quote and a double-quote - and **no** backslashes.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation! It helps me to better understand \ in Python!

Answer (score 2):

The backslash \ character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for backslash escape sequences.

Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

In strict compatibility with Standard C, up to three octal digits are accepted, but an unlimited number of hex digits is taken to be part of the hex escape (and then the lower 8 bits of the resulting hex number are used in 8-bit implementations).

Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the string. (This behavior is useful when debugging: if an escape sequence is mistyped, the resulting output is more easily recognized as broken.)

When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, backslashes are still used to quote the following character, but all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `n'. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a value string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

Comment: Thanks. What puzzled me is in my example, it doesn't escape. Single backslash produces double backslashes. Double backslashes produce Double backslashes. Triple backslashes produce quadruple backslashes.....

Comment: @jalene it’s because the interpreter shows you a Python representation of a string, not the string itself.  Use print to  see the actual result.

Comment: @jmster it indeed produced a different result when I print it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first pattern
`'@#2_#]&*^%$\]'`
`\` is not escaped so in the output one more `\` is added to escape it. 
For the second pattern
`'@#2_#]&*^%$\\]'` 
`\` is already escaped in the pattern so no new `\` in the output.
For the third pattern
`'@#2_#]&*^%$\\\]'` first `\` is escaping the second `\` and third
`\` is being escaped by adding one more `\` in the output. So four `\`.
Hope it helps.